# Azure Data Factory. Unable to load files via HTTP Connector

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

To load files from a remote server to an Azure BLOB Storage, I am working on this tutorial from Azure team: [Copy data from an HTTP endpoint by using Azure Data Factory or Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http?tabs=data-factory).

I need to load publicly available files from this [site](https://api.usaspending.gov/) through this API: Via API  `https://api.usaspending.gov/api/v2/download/disaster/`

The tutorial for using the API (and other API from the above linked site) is provided [here](https://api.usaspending.gov/docs/endpoints).

But when I run the pipeline, I get the following error:

> ErrorCode=HttpFileFailedToRead,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to read data from http server. Check the error from http server：The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.,Source=System,'

**Question**: How can we use the the above API Endpoint in Azure Data Factory to load publicly available files from their remote server?

**Remarks**: According to [their site](https://api.usaspending.gov/docs/endpoints): `/api/v2/download/disaster/  POST    Returns a zipped file containing Account and Award data for the Disaster Funding`

**Our configuration of the `Source` of ADF Pipeline**:

[image]

**The above source tests successfully as shown below**:

[image]

**The destination (an Azure Data Lake Storage) also tests successfully as shown below**:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the METHOD which you are using in your copy activity. It needs to be POST.

[image]

Also, the response is not a file but provides a link to where the file can be downloaded. See below for the sample response. This means you need another activity to actually fetch the file.

[image]

Comment: Hi @nam, If this answers your question kindly mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Your suggestion worked (thank you). But I am unable to add another activity that would actually fetch the file. I have created another post for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70140379/1232087)